# How do I parse a web page from its URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use ZenQuotes to get a random quote.

When I click on this link: https://zenquotes.io/api/random/

I get redirected to a page with a random quote in it. How can I get this text and put it into JSON in JavaScript?

I found this on a website to do a HTTP request:

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://zenquotes.io/api/quotes/';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  console.log(Http)
}
```

However, I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't have to "put it into JSON" - it _is_ JSON. You just need to get it, [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and then read out the information (note: it's an array with an object in it).

Comment: use javascript fetch api